# Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status (vba mysql recordset)

Tags: mysql, vba

I am getting the following error when trying to write the data from a table in a database into a sheet.

My code looks like this:

```
Public Sub download_nodes()

    Dim pull As New QueryHandler
    Dim rst As Recordset

    'Get info from mysql into Recordset
    With pull
      .ConnectionString = "localhost"
      .SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table_db`;"
      Set rst = .RetrieveQuery
    End With

    'Write data in worksheet "Test"
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        Sheets("Test").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End If

End Sub
```

Any idea what the issue could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is almost 1 year old but today I bumped into this error again. In these cases you need state what is your whole environment. I'm getting E_FAIL errors under Excel 2016 32-bit, MariaDB 10.1.14 and Maria ODBC driver 3.1.1 but in the past I also had that error with ODBC driver 2.0.18 and 3.0.6

I'm still not sure if this bug was reintroduced in 3.1.1 or what but it seems to be related with DATE fields. You might work around it by casting them to strings but if your environment is somewhat like mine then trying different ODBC drivers seems the easiest way to go.